# Filling Combobox depending on another Combobox from a database C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I want to fill a combo box depending on another combo box.I tried to find it for 2 days.

I have a database with 3 tables.

1. `ID, BrandName`
2. `ID, SerieName, BrandID`
3. `ID, ProfileNam, SerieID`

My Form is like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOT0C.png).

First combo box fill with `Brandname` and its working well with the code below.

```
 private void MarkaYukle()
    {
        string dbBaglantiYolu = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\\Personal Files\\Otomasyon\\VB\\SmallCNC_V01.00\\database\\database01.mdb";

        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection baglanti=new OleDbConnection(dbBaglantiYolu))
            {
                baglanti.Open();
                string dataYolu = "SELECT * FROM Markalar";
                OleDbDataAdapter adaptor = new OleDbDataAdapter(dataYolu, baglanti);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adaptor.Fill(ds);
                comboMarkaSec.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                comboMarkaSec.DisplayMember = "MarkaAdi";
                comboMarkaSec.ValueMember = "ID";

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

What I want, when I select brand, **I want `combobox2` to be filled with `series name`. But only if `BrandID` equal to selected `combobox1` `brandID.`**

For example, car brand AUDI, VOLVO for first combobox, and second show only model of car brand, A4/A3 and V40/V90 etc.

I can use `combobox2.fill` command, and also its working. But I need ID of `SeriesName` also becasue, I will use it at `listbox` to show. For example motor spec. Like 1.6lt DSG / 2.2lt Manual etc.

Hope I can explain it with my bad English. Thanks.

Comment: The Google term you are looking for is "cascading" comboboxes. All you need to do it get the id of the selected item and put that in a `WHERE` clause for the second query, then do the same thing to the second combobox that you have done with the first.

Comment: oh yes many thanks. its just too simple :)
i add for my second combobox WHERE BagliMarkaID=" + comboMarkaSec.SelectedValue  + " "
and its done.

Comment: Now read up on SQL Injection before you do it that way in real life: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work